# Attempting to INSERT string `alert("boo")` to MySQL Database but Produces 403 Error PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am attempting to save javascript source as text to a mysql table. I am using MEDIUM TEXT for the data type in the database. When testing I noticed I am unable to successfully save the text if it includes `alert();` anywhere within the textarea being saved to the database. I understand the XSS vulnerability and thought maybe it's a built-in precaution by the server provider so I even attempted to save the string in base64 encoding. Still I receive a 403 forbidden error when trying to save the source text.

The description on the 403 Forbidden error is: `You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

```
$string1 = 'console.log("test");';
//successfully saves when attempting to insert into database

$string2 = 'alert("boo");';
//error 403 Forbidden when attempting to insert into database

$string3 = 'alert("boo");';
$encstr = base64_encode($string3);
//error 403 Forbidden when attempting to insert into database
```

Any ideas how to fix or circumvent? This is a new service provider I am using (namecheap), I don't get this error when running the same code on my digitalocean VPS.

UPDATE TO SHOW SOURCE:

```
<?php
require("conn.php");

if(isset($_POST["savecode"])){
    $getuniqueid = uniqid();
    $gettime = time();

    $getscriptcode = $_POST["scriptcode"];
    $sanitizescriptcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $getscriptcode);
    //$sanitizescriptcode = htmlspecialchars($sanitizescriptcode);
    $sanitizescriptcode = base64_encode($sanitizescriptcode);
    $insertscript = "INSERT INTO scriptcode (`postid`,`content`,`ttime`) VALUES('$getuniqueid','$sanitizescriptcode','$gettime')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $insertscript)or die("Fatal error attempting to save JavaScript");

    header("Location: ?id=".$getuniqueid);
    exit();

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="hbanner"><form method="post"><button type="submit" name="savecode" id="savecode" class="btn btn-info">SAVE</button></div>
<textarea id="scriptcode" name="scriptcode" class="codeinput"></textarea></form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which framework do you use?

Comment: No framework in this case. Just vanilla PHP with `mysqli_query` and SQL statement `"INSERT INTO scriptcode (`content`) VALUES('$string2')";` and  `$string2` is escaped and htmlspecialchars before inputting into db.

Comment: would you please share your code? full version.

Comment: Updated to show additional source.

Comment: It's not related to how you are inserting data into the database. Insertion is ok. Do you use a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NameCheap uses [`ModSecurity`](http://modsecurity.org/), which is a Web Application Firewall (or WAF). A number of the filters are related to preventing cross-site-scripting. (Note: Their support can either disable it at an account level, or whitelist certain rules for you, but you have to contact them directly. They can also pull logs to tell you which filters are being hit.)

It's possible that the base64-encoded version is actually hitting a different rule, since this is commonly used by malware to obfuscate their malicious code. Another possibility is that it's the pressense of the script in the POST request, so you could try base64-encoding that before it's submitted using JavaScript (using `window.btoa(data)`) and then decoding it on the PHP side with `base64_decode`.

You can test whether it's at the MySQL level by just commenting out all of that code and seeing if you still get a `403` when submitting the form.

If it's at the SQL level, you could try to pass a chunked string with some known delimiter that wouldn't appear in your strings, then replace it out in SQL. For example, something like this:

```
$insertscript = "INSERT INTO scriptcode (`postid`,`content`,`ttime`) VALUES('$getuniqueid',REPLACE('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,chunk_split($_POST['scriptcode'],4,"†")) . "','†',""),'$gettime')";
```

In this example, `chunk_split` is inserting a special character every 4th position, and then the MySQL `REPLACE` function is stripping them out after the query is already sent to the database server.

Keep in mind that this is super hacky and somewhat inefficient—I'm just trying to offer some potential workarounds that don't involve support.

Comment: Ahh ok so it does have a protection feature. I don't mind the hack approach using a delimeter, but I'll try some work arounds or just go back to my VPS where I have full control.

Comment: @m1xolyd1an Good deal. If it helps you track down which part is the issue or work around it, feel free to accept the answer—if not, post an update and maybe we can come up with some more ideas.